# CiviMail Track Click Throughs directed to Page Not Found

Tags: civimail

Since upgrading to CiviCRM 4.6.9 on Drupal 6.37, when using track click throughs in CiviMail, links send to Page Not Found.

Answer (score 2):

What is the url to track that generates the page not found?

One common problem is that your apache/nginx rules are wrongly redirecting the url used to track the clicks to be handled by drupal

Is this a "real" 404 page (coming from your webserver) or is this drupal handling that page and generating a page not found?

Comment: All of the links in the email send readers to  Page Not Found, unless Tracking is turned off. This didn't happen before upgrading to 4.6.9, so I suspect the problem is more Civi based than Drupal or Apache based.

Comment: All the links in the email send readers to Page Not Found at (http://mysite/sites/default/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=x&qid=x), unless Tracking is turned off.

Comment: and where did you install your civicrm? into sites/default/modules or into sites/all/modules (the later is the common way)

Comment: sites/default/modules

Answer (score 0):

I thought this patch fixed the problem:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-7400

But, I spoke too soon. Still having the same "Page Not Found" issue when Tracking Click Throughs is turned on.